# Force iOS app's database to upgrade

Tags: ios, core-data, upgrade

My app's 2nd version adds two new entries to the database. But the new items are only gets listed in the app's table view if I uninstall the app from the phone and install the new version. Otherwise the new entries are not getting updated to the DB. Entries are listed in a plist file.

How do I force it to update the DB (without losing data) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have some kind of version identifier in your database, and when you app launches, always check it. If you find it is an older version, add the additional data that needs to be added than update the version number. This means that your plist needs to keep track of what is new by database version.

Note that the lack of a version identifier can be treated as a version identifier (that is `null` is older than `version 1`).